# Elasticsearch: query for not finished processes

Tags: elasticsearch

I event based (immutable) log in elasticsearch. Witch looks like this:

- (start_event, process_id)
- (event1, process_id)
- ...
- (end_event, process_id)

Is it possible to query for all records that do not have end event present for their process_id (i.e. not finished processes).

Comment: If i understand you logdifferent document (events) for 1 process_id. If you want retrive all event without a end_event, use aggregation on process_id, a subaggregation "exists" on the end_event should resolve your problem.

Comment: @LeBigCat could you provide sort example?